# WPF Image source relative path

Tags: wpf, image

I'm trying to get relative path to work for a WPF application without success.

```
public string DisplayedImage 
{
    get { return "/AppName;Images/ImageName.jpg"; }
}
```

The code above gives me IOException:'System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource '/AppName;Images/ImageName.jpg' in the output window.

Code that does work is:

```
public string DisplayedImage
{
    get
    {
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Images/ImageName.jpg");
    }          
}
```

I am wondering why the /AppName way fails. Any insight? The images are not known at compile time. This is a database application and the images are stored on the local drive, in a folder in the Application directory.

Comment: Replace *AppName* by the assembly name of your application. Read more in [this article about Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).

Comment: are you missing component/ from your path? "/AppName;component/Images/ImageName.jpg"

Comment: @Clemens I did use the my real applications name.

Comment: @geedubb I'm under the impression that ...;component... is used for images compiled into the solution. Is that correct?

Comment: Of course there should be a file named `ImageName.jpg` in a folder named `Images` in your Visual Studio project. And the *Build Action* of the image file should be `Resource`, but this is the default value for image files anyway.

Comment: @Clemens, the question author has stated that *The images are not known at compile time*, so I don't believe that they are actually *in* the project when it is built.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for pointing this out. Apparently I've read over that sentence.

Comment: @kurgan, I have a similar application set up, where it displays thousands of images (one at a time) from a network drive. I just use the exact file path and it works fine... why can't you just do that? It will save you all this trouble.

Comment: @Sheridan This application needs to be portable, data and executable. Thanks for all the responses. It is now clear how the relative path stuff works.

Comment: I'm not sure what *This application needs to be portable, data and executable* means, but that has no relevance to my comment about referencing absolute file paths. Either way, I'm glad that you now understand relative paths. Perhaps you might delete this question now, as it is no help to anyone?

Comment: @Sheridan, if the user working in the field stores some images with an absolute path on a drive say "c:\folderA\AppName\image.jpg" and then moves the application and data to another computer at head office with a path of "F:\projectX\AppName\image.jpg", the two paths will not agree. The path where the images are stored are relative the the executable, is the simplest solution.

Comment: You said *This is a database application and the images are stored on the local drive*. I said *use the exact file path to those images*.